# Views or relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, uml

What is the best for a search application which have lot of criterions :
1- make a central table which have relationship with all other tables which have criterion in their field.
or
2- make just a view and let relationship just with few table (according to logical thinking)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you are optimizing.

1. If ONLY the search, and tags are static, or their number is limited, it is better to make a huge table, with all tags as columns and true/false in cells.
2. If tags are dynamic and independent and you have to create them often and there are many of them, you can use a table for objects and a table for every tag, where only id's of the objects that "have them" lie.

Sorry, I haven't understood your examples.